# Logarithm Question $ p_1 \cdot p_2 = log(p_1) + log(p_2)? $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

why are you able to write: $ p_1 \cdot p_2 $ to: $ log(p_1) + log(p_2)  $, where p is the probability of an event occurring. 
Also, what would be the benefit of rewriting it in logs?

Comment: One can't. In fact, $\log (p_1\cdot p_2)=\log p_1 + \log p_2$.

Comment: I think I might have mis-understood this video? https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/128 Look at minute 7:24.

Comment: The instructor is *hugely* abusing notation! He's doing what's in Jonathan Y.'s equation, just omitting the first $\log$.  His point is to do log addition instead of multiplication, then take exponentials to get back to the original probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

An answer for your second question, you can find here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability